# Display of HTML5 Audio controls using PhoneGap on iOS

Tags: ios, html, audio, cordova

I've looked around a bit for an answer for this question on stackoverflow but all I can find is info about making custom play/stop/pause buttons.

I want to be able to show the audio scrubber controls in a PhoneGap app using HTML5 audio (hopefully using little or no JS as it does get processor intensive and slow down app performance).

When I test out in iOS Simulator or on my phone it just displays a blank rectangle with a play icon in it (which works and does playback audio). Maybe this is a shortfall on PhoneGap? I am just looking for a straightforward way of getting the full audio controls to show like they do in website.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really found the ideal solution I was hoping for but it's something...
Found a nice tip on using JQuery to load up some custom functions and using JQM framework for grouping radio buttons:

UPDATE: I've updated the code so that it detects what button ID it is clicking on (each radio button has unique ID) and keeps it as a variable and then runs through 'if else' statement and inserts audio tag with source dynamically into a div. I will update the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".audioPlay").click(function(){
            var audioTag = this.id;
            var loader = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
            if (audioTag=='radio-choice-h-1a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/cow.wav"></audio>';
            } else if(audioTag=='radio-choice-h-2a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/pig.wav"></audio>';
            } else if(audioTag=='radio-choice-h-3a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/sheep.wav"></audio>';
            } else if(audioTag=='radio-choice-h-4a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/lion.wav"></audio>';
            } else if(audioTag=='radio-choice-h-5a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/train.wav"></audio>';
            } else if(audioTag=='radio-choice-h-6a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/waves.wav"></audio>';
            } else if(audioTag=='radio-choice-h-7a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/truck.wav"></audio>';
            } else if(audioTag=='radio-choice-h-8a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/laughing.wav"></audio>';
            } else if(audioTag=='radio-choice-h-9a'){
                loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/birds.wav"></audio>';
            } else {
               loader.innerHTML = '<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="audio/dog.wav"></audio>'; 
            }
            $("#audio-player")[0].play();
            $("#message").text("Music started");
        })


        $(".audioPause").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
            $("#message").text("Music paused");
        })

        $(".audioStop").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
            $("#audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
            $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
        })
    })
</script>
```

I have not yet updated the code for the other control buttons. I admit my code is really messy and verbose. I did try using switch/case statements but I could not get it to work. There is surely a cleaner approach to this code but I'm quite committed to just get it working for now, been working on it long enough!

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="audioPlayer"></div>
    <form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Cow Sound Controls</legend>
        <input type="radio" class="audioPlay" name="cow-sound" id="radio-choice-h-1a" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-1a">Play</label>
        <input type="radio" class="audioPause"  name="cow-sound" id="radio-choice-h-1b" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-1b">Pause</label>
        <input type="radio" class="audioStop" id="radio-choice-h-1c" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-1c">Stop</label>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Pig Sound Controls</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="pig-sound" class="audioPlay" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">Play</label>
        <input type="radio" class="audioPause" name="pig-sound" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Pause</label>
        <input type="radio" class="audioStop" name="pig-sound" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-2c">Stop</label>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Sheep Sound Controls</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="sheep-sound" class="audioPlay" id="radio-choice-h-3a" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-3a">Play</label>
        <input type="radio" class="audioPause" name="sheep-sound"  id="radio-choice-h-3b" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-3b">Pause</label>
        <input type="radio" class="audioStop" name="sheep-sound"  id="radio-choice-h-3c" value="">
        <label for="radio-choice-h-3c">Stop</label>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

The only issue is that it keeps targeting the first  tag off the stack. Is there possible a quick and easy way to have the audio ID #audio-player get dynamically replaced when I use a different controlgroup buttons so I can target different audio tags?

Or better yet, using innerHTML to write a different src of wav file into audio tag? Stacking them up into an array and using a set of case statements? - **I kinda went this way on the solution but I haven't yet thought use an array to output the innerHTML. Not really sure if it is really worth it...**